# Get number from a string which also includes datetime in C#

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I have this string :

> Ümraniye Tapu Müdürlüğünde ve Ümraniye Belediyesi İmar Müdürlüğünde
>   20.08.2014 onay tarih ve 254 sayılı mimari projesi incelenmiştir.

I'm getting datetime : like this :

```
t = DateTime.Parse(Regex.Match(mimaristring, @"\d(\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)").Value);
```

I'm trying to get 254 like this :

```
num = Regex.Match(mimaristring, @"\d+").Value;
```

But instead of 254, I get 20. How can I skip datetime and get 254?

NOTE: Sometimes, I have numbers like `123/456`, not just `254`, and I need to get them, too.

Comment: The above regex by @WiktorStribiżew will give you the last numeric character(s) in your string. But is that really what you are looking for?

Comment: @some1: I posted an alternative solution, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perhaps jason is just looking for a simple `\s\d+\s` ?  that is just a numeric sequence without anything in between, and with spaces around it

Comment: Well, a bit more complicated than that. But if the value is followed with a comma, or the value is at the end of the string, then `\s` won't let it be matched. @some1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the whole number not inside dots+digits, you need to use lookarounds:

```
@"(?<!\d\.)\b\d+(?:/\d+)?\b(?!\.\d)"
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cd%5c.)%5cb%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%2f%5cd%2b)%3f%5cb(%3f!%5c.%5cd)&i=%c3%9cmraniye+Tapu+M%c3%bcd%c3%bcrl%c3%bc%c4%9f%c3%bcnde+ve+%c3%9cmraniye+Belediyesi+%c4%b0mar+M%c3%bcd%c3%bcrl%c3%bc%c4%9f%c3%bcnde+20.08.2014+onay+tarih+ve+254%2f234+say%c4%b1l%c4%b1+mimari+projesi+incelenmi%c5%9ftir.)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `(?<!\d\.)` - no match if there is a `digit`+`.` before the current location
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d+(?:/\d+)?` - 1+ digits optionally followed with `/` and 1+ digits
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary
- `(?!\.\d)` - fail the match if there is a dot followed with a digit.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/BcQBj9):

```
var s = "Ümraniye Tapu Müdürlüğünde ve Ümraniye Belediyesi İmar Müdürlüğünde 20.08.2014 onay tarih ve 254 sayılı mimari projesi incelenmiştir.";
var pat = @"(?<!\d\.)\b\d+(?:/\d+)?\b(?!\.\d)";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(s, pat).Value);
```

Comment: If I have "/", would it be ok? I mean I can have a number like this : 123/456 and it will be ok.

Comment: Yes, just add it into a character class - `[/.]`

Comment: I don't understand, I mean I have 123/456 and I need to get whole of it. Where should I add `[/ .]`

Comment: Excuse me, you mean that is the value you have instead `254`? Please update the question.

Comment: Sometimes yes, some numbers are normal numbers like 254, some of them are like 123/456, I want to get both of them.